# TextView Text clips

Tags: android, textview

[image]

In the above image the gravity is set to right, don't know why the text slices out at the end.

TextView code is as shown below

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Month/Day/Year"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:onClick="onClickDateField"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    style="@style/FormFont"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/form_date"
    android:background="#ffffab5d" />
```

Style code is also listed below.

```
<style name="FormFont">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">Roboto-Bold</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic|bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#009ACD</item>
</style>
```

Also, dimension is

```
<dimen name="form_date">35dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`, gives you a rectangle for wrapped content rendering. All will work well for normal text (`non-italic`).

Once you have `italic` text enabled, the wrapped text will try to fit into the rectangle and hence the rightmost character will be cut off unless its un-cut-able.

**Solution 1 :**

you can add padding to `TextView` field like

```
android:paddingRight="3dp"
```

**Solution 2 :**

you can add just extra space to the end of the text. If you add `\u0020` to the end of the Text.

Comment: Adding paddingRight , but size equivalent to texSize. i.e android:paddingRight="@dimen/form_date"

Comment: @andyPaul glad to know that. But I think in your case you are using `35dp` padding is too large try to decrease it to see `Text` in right side.

Answer (score 1):

You can force a `TextView` to draw outside of its bounds by giving it a text shadow. If you set the shadow color to transparent, then you have your solution! Add these to your `TextView`:

```
android:shadowColor="#00FFFFFF"
android:shadowDx="48"
android:shadowDy="0"
android:shadowRadius="1"
```

In my testing I found that #00000000 didn't work, 48 was a sufficient size to show all clipped text, and shadowDy and shadowRadius were necessary.